# How to read output of a vector<string> with a certain number of words to a line?

Tags: c++, string, vector, cout

I am really struggling with a question I am working through in a book. I am learning C++ by myself and am only up to Chapter 3, but this question has really got me stuck.

The question is:
"Read a sequence of words from din and store the values [in] a vector. After you've read all the words, process the vector and change each word to uppercase. Print the transformed elements, eight words to a line." - Exercise 3.17 in C++ Primer (5th Edition)

I can store in vector and change all words to uppercase no problem. It is the printing them out thing that is an issue.

Pleas could you help me!! I am so frustrated!!! Please also keep it really nice and simple, it is only Chapter 3 and I'd like to write the answer at thatlevel rather than complicated (for my current level) code.

Greatly appreciate all help!!

Here's my code right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string; using std::vector; using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> v1;  // Create an empty vector

    string words;     // Create a string "words"
    string output;

    while (cin >> words) {
        v1.push_back(words);
    }
    for (auto i = 0; i<v1.size(); ++i){
        for (auto &s : v1) {
            for (auto &c : s)
                c = toupper(c);
        }
        cout << v1[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, vector comes out perfectly, but now the thing is I need it to print 8 words to a line. (i.e. if I have 24 words in the string then it should print out all the words but on 3 lines)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what Jon suggested, using modulus operator.

```
for (int i = 0, i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    for (auto &c : v1[i]) {
        c = toupper(c)
    }

    // satisfying 8-per-line requirement
    if (i % 8 == 0) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << v1[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite seem to work, I just get this out: HOW 
MANY 
APPLES 
ARE 
THEREIN 
AN 
ORCHARD 
OF ORANGES?

Comment: sorry, each of those outputs was on a new line

Comment: I made a slight modification to when newline is emitted. Could you try this: https://gist.github.com/4481780 ?

Comment: Ah man! So so so close!!! When I put in a string it prints the first word on one line, then moves to a new line prints 8 words and then the next 8 as it should... so why would it be printing a single word on a line first? The other thing is, how exactly is the code working?! You may just be my favourite person alive today!!! So so close! Thank you!!!

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator, look it up. To fix the problem you describe, use an offset `(i+1)%8`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to keep track of the number of words that have been printed thus far on the current line, and end the line when that count exceeds 8:

```
int count = 0;
const int max = 8;

for (const auto& word : words) {
  cout << word << ' ';

  // One more word has been printed.
  ++count;

  // If the count exceeds the maximum number of words per line...
  if (count > max) {

    // ...then move to the next line.
    count = 0;
    cout << '\n';

  }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, yea, I can see how that works, nice and simple!... now for the really stupid question... at what point in my code would I insert this?

Comment: Haha, tried that (maybe in the wrong place) and got this out: o r a n g e s ? HOW o r a n g e s ? MANY o r a n g e s ? APPLES o r a n g e s ? ARE o r a n g e s ? THERE o r a n g e s ? IN o r a n g e s ? AN o r a n g e s ? ORCHARD o r a n g e s ? OF o r a n g e s ? 
ORANGES?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope You are familier with iterators since you are working with STL.The following example is with iterator.

```
vector<string>::iterator itrbegin = v1.begin();
vector<string>::iterator itrend = v1.end();
int count = 0;
while(itrbegin != itrend)
{
  cout<<*itrbegin;
  count++;
  if(count % 8 == 0)
  {
    cout<<endl;  
  }
 itrbegin++;
}
```

This should work and print out the vector. You should put it after the vector has been fully populated with strings. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the input! Haha, that's the frustrating thing about this exercise... the next page after the exercise questions introduces iterators. So this exercise is asking for the solution without the use of iterators. Darnd

Comment: Haha, yea! Next page is a'comin!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would copy a `vector` to `cout` using `copy` and an `ostream_iterator`:

```
vector<string> words;
copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
```

The last parameter determines the separator, a space in this case.

Going from `begin` to `end` copies the whole `vector`. We want to use something instead of `begin` and `end` so that we can move forward through the vector in chunks of 8, maybe fewer in the final chunk.

```
int chunk_size = 8;

auto chunk_begin = words.begin();
while(disance(chunk_begin, words.end()) >= chunk_size) {
    auto chunk_end = chunk_begin;
    advance(chunk_end, chunk_size);
    copy(chunk_begin, chunk_end, ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    chunk_begin = chunk_end;
    cout << endl;
}
copy(chunk_begin, words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
```

**P.S.** I often recommend encapsulation. Thinking about it some more, we could encapsulate the output iterator to keep track and write a newline, instead of a space after every 8 assignments. This is quite a lot of work, but worth bearing in mind, as re-use, readbility, code size, testing, etc, are all affected:

```
copy(words.begin(), words.end(),
     chunked_ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " ", 8, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but I bumped into the same problem while going through the book (5 Ed.) and found a solution that is more consistent with the contents explained in the book until this chapter (Ch.3). The only issue not covered in the book at this point is the use of the modulus method to implement a counter that runs slower than the loop iterator, but the rest is taken from there.

`int main () {
    vector<string> sentence;
    string word;
    while (cin >> word) // add words from input
        sentence.push_back(word);
    unsigned cnt = 1; // initialize counter 
    for (auto &w: sentence) { 
        for (auto &c: w) // uppercase word
            c = toupper(c);
        cout << w << " "; // print word
        if (cnt%8 == 0)
            cout << endl; // eol every 8 counts
        ++cnt;
    }
    cout << endl; // extra eol
    return 0;
}`